# How do I prove $x^n < x^m$ when $m > n$ and $x > 1$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Title

I made an attempt at it here:

$x^n < x^m$ when $m > n$ and $x > 1$, $m$ and $n$ are naturals

so divide both sides by $x^n$

so

$1 < x^{m-n}$

but here i am stuck.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x > 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2 > x \quad \Rightarrow x^3 > x^2 \ \ldots$. By induction, $x^{n+1} > x^n$. Thus, $x^m \geq x^{n+1} > x^n$.

Comment: I agree with you. I see that my answer is incomplete. Thank you.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realized that OP specified that they are, in fact, natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to show that $f(x) = c^x > 1$ when $c>1$ for all $x>0$.

Consider $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ to show that $f$ is a strictly increasing function, and evaluate $f(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $m>n$ then $m-n>0$, and since $x>1$, $x$ to any positive power will be greater than $1$, which is what you wanted.

Comment: oh. i didn't know i could just say that haha. thanks, will accept your answer when i can.

Comment: If you want to prove it rigorously, you can adapt the proof given by @MathFacts.